# JavaScript runtime error: Member not found

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication

I faced this error for the first time and never before

I have asp.net login control , when press on it , I receive an error says 
JavaScript runtime error: Member not found.

in the aspx page the debugger highlighted the portion

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();  << this section in yellow highlight  
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

so , why I received this error
thank you

Comment: I guess the server side is throwing an exception. Have you looked into that?

Comment: What browser are you using? If IE, what document mode? Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: @StevenLemmens No, this error is clearly coming from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error , because in the default.aspx page I have also an html button its name submit , and this button cause a conflict between the login control and submit button .